# Multilevel Expandable Listview

Tags: android, android-expandable-list-view

I'm trying to add values into the parent groupPosition[0] particularly. But its reflecting to all the groupPositions of parent list item. Plesae help me guys.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    ExpandableListView explvlist;
    ArrayList<String> StringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> StringArrayChild=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayValueAddFunction();
        ArrayValueAddFunction_Level2();
        explvlist = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ParentLevel);
        explvlist.setAdapter(new ParentLevel(StringArray)); 
    }
    private void ArrayValueAddFunction_Level2() {
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item1");
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item2");
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item3");
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item4");
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item5");
        StringArrayChild.add("Level1 item6");
    }
    private void ArrayValueAddFunction() {
        StringArray.add("ONE");
        StringArray.add("TWO");
        StringArray.add("THREE");
        StringArray.add("FOUR");
        StringArray.add("FIVE");
        StringArray.add("SIX");
    }
    public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        ArrayList<String> StringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        private Context context;
        public ParentLevel(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {
            this.StringArray=stringArray;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return arg1;
        }
        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(MainActivity.this);

                SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());
                SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);
                return SecondLevelexplv;
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 3;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return StringArray.size();
        }
        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            if (groupPosition==0) {
                tv.append(StringArray.get(0));
            }else if (groupPosition==1){
                tv.append(StringArray.get(1));
            }else if (groupPosition==2){
                tv.append(StringArray.get(2));
            }else if (groupPosition==3){
                tv.append(StringArray.get(3));
            }else if (groupPosition==4){
                tv.append(StringArray.get(4));
            }else if (groupPosition==5){
                tv.append(StringArray.get(5));
            }
            return tv;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
        public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
        {

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
            {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
            {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                tv.setText("child");
                tv.setPadding(15, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                return tv;
            }
            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return 6;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }
            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
            {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                     View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                if (groupPosition==0) {
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(0));
                }else if (groupPosition==1){
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(1));
                }else if (groupPosition==2){
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(2));
                }else if (groupPosition==3){
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(3));
                }else if (groupPosition==4){
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(4));
                }else if (groupPosition==5){
                    tv.append(StringArrayChild.get(5));
                }
                tv.setPadding(12, 7, 7, 7);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                return tv;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    }
```

CustExpListview

```
     class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView
     {
    int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;
    public CustExpListview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Layout design with expandableListView

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ParentLevel"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The image given below is the output, all the items are coming into all the positions, but i need to put position[0], but its reflecting to all the groupPositins of parent list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem happens at `getGroupView`.  `groupPosition` returns 0 always. Check your code for that issue. 
By the way, you can use this [NLeveLExpandableListView](https://github.com/sadra/NLeveLExpandableListView).

Comment: thanks bro, for your valuable reply..I need extended child items for Root1 and root2 only, and for the remaining roots i need only Child items.. I eagerly waiting for your reply

Comment: Your code is totally wrong and it makes some unnecessary loops. There are many ways to make `NLevelxpandable ListView` for example check [this blog post](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/expandablelistadapter-example-android.html) about how to create **Expandable NLevel List**.

Comment: @SadraIsapanahAmlashi any hint on collapse all and expand all items together for your github link ?